# Testbed for testing navigation algorithms

Tags: navigation, routing

I'm looking for a testbed (simulator or web-based interface that lets me to have control on a robot) for testing different routing and navigation algorithms. Is there such a system on the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use player/stage or gazebo